# Primefaces calendar picker doesn't work with MMM pattern

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I'd like to use a Calendar component from the primefaces as shown here: [PrimeFaces - ShowCase : Calendar - Time](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarTime.jsf)

```
<p:calendar id="startDateSelected" value="#{myBB.dateSelected}" 
pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy">
```

`dateSelected` is just a plain `Date()`

It works fine for the patterns mentioned in the showcase, but I'd like to use the following pattern:

```
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm
```

When I use this, the dialog with picker doesn't show up. When I remove the time from the pattern, the picker works(only for date obviously) and if I change `MMM` to `MM`, it also works.

- `dd-MMM-yyyy` works
- `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` works
- `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm` doesn't work

So the only problem is a combination of MMM and time. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used following pattern at my side.

#### EEE, dd MMM, yyyy

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date3}" pattern="EEE, dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm" />
```

#### EEE, dd MM, yyyy

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date2}" pattern="EEE, dd MM, yyyy HH:mm" />
```

It is wokring fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. After all I found out, that the problem was with some crazy locale set in the view. The component works flawlessly.