# Primefaces 4.0.16 <p:calendar> Doesn't show proper Time sliders

Tags: java, xml, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

**Versions**
Primefaces : 4.0.16
JSF: 2
So I have this `<p:calendar>` where I would like make it possible to pick both a date and a time.

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="fromCal" id="fromDate" locale="#{lsutil:getLocale()}" pattern="#{lsutil:getCalendarDateTimeOnly()}" navigator="true"
                        onfocus="Util.dateMask(this,'#{lsutil:getCalendarDateTimeOnly()}');" value="#{createTestPlanController.model.timeFrom}"
                        required="true" title="#{component.valid ? '' : msg['createTestPlan.testPlanFailedInvalidTimeRange']}" />
```

And as you can see I have in the `<p:calendar>` the `pattern=”MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm”`within the `pattern="#{lsutil:getCalendarDateTimeOnly()}"`

I might add that it opens in af `<ui:composition>` - do not know if that has anything to do with it ?

The `pattern="#{lsutil:getCalendarDateTimeOnly()}"` Calls my function in my .xml file:

```
<function>
     <function-name>getCalendarDateTimeOnly</function-name>
     <function-class>lyngsoe.catellae.infrastructure.CatellaeUtils</function-class>
     <function-signature>java.lang.String getCalendarDateTimeOnly()</function-signature>
</function>
```

And from here it drills down to my .java file

```
public static String getCalendarDateTimeOnly(){
    return CatellaeUtils.getCurrentUser().getCalendarDateTimeOnlyString();
}
```

drill downs again to another .java file where my method for removing the EEE in the date string I get, the EEE that represents the day of the week with (MON, WED, SAT etc.)

```
public String getCalendarDateTimeOnlyString()
{
    String dTFS = this.getDateTimeFormatString();
    String patternRegex = "[a-zA-z][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]\\s";
    try {
        String dateTimeOnlyString = dTFS.replaceFirst(patternRegex,"");
        return dateTimeOnlyString;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

I am using the replaceFirst filter to go from **EEE dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss** to **dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss** and I save that in the variable `dateTimeOnlyString` and returning it. As far as I can see in the F12 of Chrome it does take time with, **if** I type it in manually. There are no sliders as shown in the [Primefaces Doc 4.0](http://file:///C:/Users/jkj/Downloads/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2%20(1).pdf) on page 52 at the buttom **Timepicker**

---

**Tried a simpel solution**

So for the sake of argument, I wanted to try a simpel `<p:calendar>` to see if it worked, it did not.

```
<p:calendar id="fromTime" value="#{createTestPlanController.model.timeFrom}" pattern="HH:mm" timeOnly="true"
```

What I get here is a field, when first reloaded I get the prober time of the day, but when I click it and want to change the time, it opens the calendar view.
Just as shown top of page 44 in [Primefaces Doc 4.0](http://file:///C:/Users/jkj/Downloads/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2%20(1).pdf)

---

Now from what I can read in the [Primefaces Doc 4.0](http://file:///C:/Users/jkj/Downloads/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2%20(1).pdf) I am doing what it says I should be doing, as to getting the results shown at the buttom of page 52

at current state: it will not be possible to update my primefaces version.

**Questions with a possible solution**
[Primefaces calendar picker doesn't work with MMM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476680/primefaces-calendar-picker-doesnt-work-with-mmm-pattern)
 - *the problem was with some crazy locale set in the view* can not see the solution really.

Comment: The next step, that I can think of and not using     http://stackoverflow.com/a/14662790/3430698 Datejs is to use a `<p:inputText>` with a regex to validate on the timestamp.    
[How to check Regular Expression for Timestamp in GWT? Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662597/how-to-check-regular-expression-for-timestamp-in-gwt)

Comment: Or I could make use of the <p:inputMask> with `mask="99:99:99"` Equivalent `pattern="HH:mm:ss"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution, for me was to make use of a `inputMask` and then drag that down, make a timestamp from the date and the time chosen and then save it.

Not a prober solution in my mind, but it did the job.

IF there is people out there, that knows a really solution, so I can make use of the calendar only - I am more the happy to take the advice :)